# Better way of hiding entries not created by current user in Django?

Tags: python, django, database, class

Im pretty new to Django, and right now I have created a site that lets users register/login, make entries that are associated to that user via a "user" field in the entries database.

Iv'e managed to get all the functionality of hiding other users entries by adding `get_queryset()` methods that only return the current users entries.

But I feel like this is a bad way of doing this.
I feel like im reusing a lot of code and that there could be backdoors to display other users entries.

**Is there a way to completely disable other users entries from the current user, not just *not display it*?**

views.py

```
class EntryListView(LockedView, ListView):
    model = Entry

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(user=self.request.user).order_by("-date_created")

class EntryDetailView(LockedView, DetailView):
    model = Entry

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(user=self.request.user)

class EntryCreateView(LockedView, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Entry
    fields = ["title", "content"]
    success_url = reverse_lazy("entry-list")
    success_message = "Your new entry was created!"

    def form_valid(self, form):
         user = self.request.user
         form.instance.user = user
         return super(EntryCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(user=self.request.user)

class EntryUpdateView(LockedView, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Entry
    fields = ["title", "content"]
    success_message = "Your entry was updated!"

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy(
            "entry-detail",
            kwargs={"pk": self.object.pk}
        )

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: You can easily combine all four views in one `viewsets.GenericViewSet`. That will let you do all operations you want in one view with only one url to create and also you can provide the user through `perform_create` method so that way you won't need to validate form.

Comment: Aside from my code being longer and messier, is there a security concern handling entries like this?

Comment: I think it is valid for handling entries.

Comment: Great. I would like to combine my views into one like you said, but I dont really understand how that works. Can I still have all my url paths in urls.py but them all pointing to this one new GenericViewSet?

Comment: I've posted an answer explaining how to create a viewset.

Answer (score 0):

Create, Detail and Update views are referring to one single entry (and relation with this entry is made from url kwarg (it can be by generic 'pk' or 'slug' etc), so get_queryset inside those 3 views are not actually helping.

If you open an Entry inside browser, you will se the url is something like /entry/<id_of_entry> so if you change that value you will access to different object. If you want to prevent users from accessing entries that doesn't belong to them, you can create some mixin like this:

```
class EntryMixin:
"""
Prevent users to access entries that has different author
"""
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.get_object().user == request.user:
        raise PermissionError
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

What is happening here is every time when user access certain view, it will check if he is assigned to that object (note that this mixin will work only with single object views (detail, update, delete), for list will need to modify.

Comment: Right now accessing a /entry/<id_of_entry> that is not made by that current user throws a Not Found error, which is what I want. What is the benefits of handling it in an EntryMixin class like you wrote?

Comment: A queryset is likely to be edited later, and the person doing that might remove or break the user filter, not appreciating its importance. Whereas removing a Mixin that specifically raises a PermissionError, would be explicitly foolish :-)

Comment: Oo I understand, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a serializer for `Entry` model and provide the field you want to display. Make the user field read_only so that.

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class EntriesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'user': {'read_only': True}
        }
```

Then create a Viewset for entries that can easily perform crud operations. override the `get_queryset` method to get current user records. Also override `perform_create` method to provide current user as the entry'e user while creating a new record.

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, mixins
from .serializers import EntriesSerializer

class EntriesViewSet(
        mixins.CreateModelMixin,
        mixins.ListModelMixin,
        mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
        mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
        mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
        viewsets.GenericViewSet
    ):
    serializer_class = EntriesSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Entry.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return queryset

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Create a router for viewset and register the viewset to the router. Then include the router's urls in urlpatterns.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from . import views

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('entries', EntriesViewSet, basename='entries')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Now you can access the list of all entries created by the current user through `/entries/` and to get details of a single entry use `/entries/<entry_id>/`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have been able to implement this and i get the users entries on ```/entries/``` and the specific entry on ```/entries/<entry_id>``` etc. This is shown in the Django Rest Framework browsable API. But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to implement this data into my current html templates. For instance, when calling ```{{ entry.content }}``` in my html template, where is it actually looking for that data? Sorry, this is a bit over my head here, but I am starting to put pieces together.

Comment: Ok so you want to show that in your template, I thought you wanted to create an API for it. I am so sorry i misread the question.

Comment: Alright iv'e reverted the changes haha, I do not need an API right now. But do you still recommend combining my views?

Comment: No don't combine the views if want to render a different template for each view.

Comment: Alright, thank you anyways, learning from everything. 